# Issue Connecting BlockScout to Ethereum Private Network

Tags: blockscout

I have set up BlockScout using Docker for my Ethereum private network. All the containers are functioning correctly, and the backend is successfully connected to the Ethereum node. However, I'm facing a WebSocket connection error:

> _app-559dd2f562b9bf97.js:18 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket/v2/websocket?vsn=2.0.0' failed:

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or can provide steps to troubleshoot and rectify this error, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you for your support.